# i got the error When i printing the inorder traversing in my C code which is given below

Tags: c

When i print **Binary Search Tree nodes in Inorder Traversal:** it only prints 1st element.
it takes the input from user and prints the user input but it does not print inorder traversing
Also please explain me execution of for loop part.

1. Can we do this code in another way?
   Also how we can perform deletion operation?

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};


void inorder(struct node *root)
{
    if(root)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("  %d",root->data);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n , i;
    struct node *p , *q , *root;
    printf("Enter the number of nodes to be insert: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("\nPlease enter the numbers to be insert: ");

    for(i=0;i<i++)
    {
        p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        scanf("%d",&p->data);
        p->left = NULL;
        p->right = NULL;
        if(i == 0)
        {
            root = p; // root always point to the root node
        }
        else
        {
            q = root;   // q is used to traverse the tree
            while(1)
            {
                if(p->data > q->data)
                {
                    if(q->right == NULL)
                        {
                        q->right = p;
                        break;
                        }
                    else
                        q = q->right;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(q->left == NULL)
                        {
                        q->left = p;
                        break;
                        }
                    else
                        q = q->left;
                }
            }

        }

    }

printf("\nBinary Search Tree nodes in Inorder Traversal: ");
inorder(root);
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error (like a crash) or does it just no behave as expected? Did you already step through the program with your debugger and inspect the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the cause of the problem is this condition:

```
for(i=0;i<i++)
```

`i<i++` causes undefained behaviour, because you read and write `i` without a sequence point in between. It's also logically wrong, because you don't use `n` at all. I think you wanted this instead:

```
//         VVV
for(i=0; i < n; i++)
```

Comment: In addition to the sequence point, the `for (..; ...)` won't compile due to missing the 2nd `';'` -- when added, then the sequence point issue pops up. The header should also be `stdio.h` (not `conio.h`) otherwise neither `printf()` or `scanf()` are defined.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, you are right. I should add these points when I find time for it.